# "gcloud source repos clone default local-directory-name" not working

Tags: git, google-app-engine, gcloud

I am trying to clone my project and since the "gcloud init *project-name*" is deprecated I followed the following steps.

1) "gcloud init" and entered the right options in the interactive menu.

2) "gcloud source repos clone default *local-directory-name*"

but it keeps asking me for user name and password.

I also executed 
"gcloud auth login" and  "git config credential.helper gcloud.sh" commands

but still asks me for username and password.

Comment: That's strange.  Usually running `git config credential.helper gcloud.sh` fixes this problem.

Comment: The Cloud SDK git credential helper is called `git-credential-gcloud.sh`, not `gcloud.sh`. Does that fix your problem? Also, make sure that this command is on your `$PATH`.

Comment: This may also be related to a Git bug with credential helpers with spaces on in file paths on Windows; are you running Windows, and does your Cloud SDK install directory have spaces?

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\git-credential-gcloud.cmd get: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\git-credential-gcloud.cmd get: -c: line 0: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\git-credential-gcloud.cmd get'

Comment: I get above two messages before being asked for credentials. Thanks for the help !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to a bug in the Cloud SDK that will be fixed in version 0.9.82.

Apologies for the inconvenience! In the mean time, you should be able to work around by running `git clone` directly:

```
> git clone 'https://source.developers.google.com/p/PROJECTID/r/default' --config credential.helper=git-credential-gcloud.cmd
```

**Note:** make sure that `git-credential-gcloud.cmd` is on your `%PATH%` first, and make sure to substitute your project's ID for `PROJECTID`.

Comment: thank you !! works after updating to Cloud SDK to 0.9.82

Comment: I get this `Cloning into 'default'...
git: 'credential-git-credential-gcloud.cmd' is not a git command.\n See 'git --help'.\n
Username for 'https://source.developers.google.com':`